# How can i change the text in a "password forgot" email in Laravel?

Tags: laravel

In a Laravel project in the folder app/mail there is a file called WelcomeDogSchoolManager.php

In this file I can see the text that is being sent when a new user registers himself.

Within this file, I can see the following code:

```
@component('mail::button', ['url' => $passwordResetUrl])
    Registreren
@endcomponent
```

Unfortunately, the developer left a mistake in the $passwordResetUrl (leaving it at "https://login..{domain}.nl" instead of the required "https://login.{domain}.nl"

This causes all my users being unable to register (unless they manipulate the URL).

Where in the Laravel Project can I search for the option to change the $passwordResetUrl?

I have no working knowledge of Laravel and am basically just searching through all the files on the server using Filezilla, trying to figure it all out. I got to this point, but have no idea how to proceed further.

Any tips are appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

if your're using Laravel version lower then 6 then search for forget controller. It's basically inside that folder because email is triggered from that controller. Hopefully, you'll find the parameter which is passing to the WelcomeDogSchoolManager class.

Comment: Thank you for helping out! I have been able to find a folder called app/http/controllers, however i did not find something called forgetcontroller.php. I checked all the files in that folder, but still couldn't find anything that said something about the parameter. Am I looking in the right place? Or am i doing something wrong?

Comment: i did find this one:         

$this->passwordResetUrl = url(route('password.reset', [
            'token' => $token,
            'email' => $this->user->email,
        ], false));

Is this helpful?